# Add a link to HTML, CSS accordion

Tags: html, css, image, formatting, accordion

I am looking to add individual links to the images on a HTML/CSS accordion - however, each time I wrap the img-source in an  tag, the formatting of the image block is affected.

The code without the  tag is below:

https://codepen.io/knyttneve/pen/YgZbLO

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4% 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 0 2%;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  line-height: 0;
}

.box>img {
  width: 200%;
  height: calc(100% - 10vh);
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.box>span {
  font-size: 3.8vh;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10vh;
  line-height: 2.6;
}

.box:hover {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.box:hover>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Accordion Slider</h1>

<div class="accordion">

  <!-- BOX 1 -->
  <div class="box a1">
    <div class="image_1">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- BOX 2 -->
  <div class="box a2">
    <div class="image_2">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- BOX 3 -->
  <div class="box a3">
    <div class="image_3">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- BOX 1 -->
  <div class="box a4">
    <div class="image_4">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- BOX 5 -->
  <div class="box a5">
    <div class="image_5">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is what it looks like with an  tag:
[Accordion Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NJpQ.jpg)

What is the way to add a link to the image source without affecting the formatting of the block?

Comment: If you add the box class to the a tag when you wrap it around the img tag it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.box > img` properties go to the wrapping anchor tag. And `.box:hover > img` has to be changed to `.box:hover > a`. Only included the changed parts of your CSS.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x800">
    </a>

    <span>CSS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x802">
    </a>

    <span>Image</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x804"></a>

    <span>Hover</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#"> <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x806"></a>

    <span>Effect</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.box > a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200%;
  height: calc(100% - 10vh);
  transition: .5s;
}

.box > a > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; 
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:hover > a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of warping your box as a `<div>` wrap it with the `<a>` tag and add the `box` class to it, this should work.